# android studio launch error: Missing MSCVR100.dll

Tags: android-studio

I am using Win 7 x64, I have installed Java SDK and Android Studio (both 64bit versions).
When I try to launch Android studio, I receive the error message: 
    The program can't start because MSCVCR100.dll is missing from your computer....
I have run the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64) but it hasn't fixed it.

Comment: The program shortcut for Android Studio on the Start menu was not correct. It was pointing to the bin folder: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\bin\studio64.exe" (incorrect)

I found the correct executable in the main directory of android-studio:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\studio64.exe

When I open that one, it works.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, download the appropiate file for your version of Windows and just install it:

- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/confirmation.aspx?id=5555)
- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=14632)

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=5555 (x86)
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632
(x64) 
-- these are the links to english-us